# how to change page in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have 2 pages and when i want to show next page, second page shown but suddenly back to previous page. this is my code

```
$(document).on('click', '#homeTitleSearch', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //  halopino.titleSearchBar.init();
  $.mobile.changePage('#second', {
    transition: 'slide',
    allowSamePageTransition: true,
    reverse: false
  });
});
```

Comment: remove this `allowSamePageTransition: true`. It triggers change page animation but remains on same view/page.

Comment: thanks Omar, i found my mistake. in my init code i use jquery code to hide/show my default page. i remove it and it works...